# View model data to json conversion

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

1st time poster, new to mvc, just trying to convert some of my model data to json, however I can't access @json.encode which is mentioned in the tutorial I was using. Any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome,

First add the following using statement to the view

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json
```

now, use the following to convert your model

```
@Html.Raw(@JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model))
```